# Windows Infrastructure as Code (IaC) support

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am using on-prem infrastructure with VM:s, on Windows 2012R2. I've tried to find tools to incorporate IaC, but I haven't found any tool for this. Chef, Ansible, etc. are only for Linux if I'm not mistaken. I think for Azure there's something, but that I can't use here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you have missed something to conclude that chef is not meant for windows. Chef have extensive support for windows and azure.

You can start looking at chef documentations:-

- https://www.chef.io/implementations/windows/
- https://docs.chef.io/windows.html

For learning, you can refer:-

- https://learn.chef.io/tutorials/learn-the-basics/windows/

Answer (score 0):

[Inedo Otter](http://inedo.com/otter) was built for Windows and integrates with PowerShell DSC. Might be a better fit if you're looking for a Windows strong IaC solution.

Answer (score 0):

Ansible also does have support for Windows, check out the documentation here:
[Ansible for Windows notes](https://www.ansible.com/windows)
[Ansible Windows Documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_windows.html)